# OpenVPN Disk I/O

Tags: openvpn

I've asked on the bona fide OpenVPN forum but no response. Whenever I connect to an OpenVPN server using OpenVPN client on Microsoft Windows, it immediately starts writing to disk at about 300k/s sustained throughout my session judging by the Microsoft Performance Monitor. It seems that it is recording my session. Is this to be expected and can it be turned off ?

Comment: If you are unsure what data is written to which file use Sysinternal Process Monitor to check what files are written by OpenVPN.

Comment: @Robert - I gave it a shot. The list of files are quite long and the tool cannot discern which file receives the I/O. I noticed two named pipes. Microsoft Performance Monitor could be fooled into thinking i/o on the pipe between sub--processes are disk i/o is probably one possibility

Comment: A named pipe would be an explanation. The key to success in process Monitor is to exclude all processes that are common to Windows (e.g. Explorer.exe and so on). After excluding 20-30 processes the remaining entries will be more focused.